# How to manipulate HTML in Flutter webview?

Tags: javascript, html, flutter, dart, flutterwebviewplugin

I am load website with Flutter webview. But I want replace HTML element when it load. For example:

```
<span class="name">Replace text</span>
```

How to do?

Comment: Hi, you could attach a handler to the load event `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() { // do my replacement });`

Comment: @IronMan How to do with Flutter webview?

Answer (score 6):

So, it depends what library you are using to load your webview.

I have had some good success using `webview_flutter_plus` (https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter_plus).

With this, you just need to wait for your html to load and inject some javascript to modify whatever html you want.

Like this:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WebViewPlus(
        initialUrl: myUrl,
        javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
        onWebViewCreated: (WebViewPlusController webViewController) {
            _webViewController = webViewController;
        },
        onPageFinished: (String url) {
            _webViewController.evaluateJavascript('document.querySelector(".name").innerHTML = "new text";');
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: dear @Didier Prophete I using this way but it seems evaluating jave script takes too long what I could done about that

Comment: Yeah. The truth is that binging up a webview inside a native app in flutter does take some time (like half a second). After that I think the js evaluation is fine but that initial time is a giant pain. Not sure there is much we can do there until flutter itself improves the webview perf (and there as well, I am not sure flutter can do anything. It might just be that a webview is an expensive class to instanciate...)

Comment: Dear is there a way I could manage to not showing the webview until it evaluate, I mean the evaluation happens on onpagefinished callback  and that it self need some time to be fired

Comment: yes @kikicoder, that's exactly what I do in my own code. I basically hide the webview (I put it in a stack, below a splash page) until onPageFinished is invoked...